# EGit: Show branch next to project in Eclipse/Aptana

Tags: eclipse, git, aptana, egit, aptana3

In Aptana Studio 3, I have 2 projects (*Project A* and *Project B*):

[image]

EGit displays the current branch next to a project when it is opened. It only does this when the *.git* folder is in the project's root (Project A) and not when it is in a sub folder).

I tried looking at the Team settings (from the context menu) and the project's properties, but there are no settings that allow me to tell the IDE it should look in a sub folder for picking up Git repositories.

Is there a way to display the name of the current Git branch next to the project when it has its Git repository folder in a sub folder?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this as well. I think it's a bug in eGit. I haven't found a way to get rid of it; other plugins had a "refresh" menu item where I could force a refresh but eGit doesn't have this. The normal project refresh (<kbd>F5</kbd>) doesn't seem to help, nor does restart.

Eventually, eGit should recover by itself.